# What is the difference between Shockwave Flash and Adobe Flash?

Tags: flash-player, adobe-flash, browser-plugin

[Shockwave Player](http://get.adobe.com/shockwave/) and [Flash Player](http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/) both run "flash" contents? On my browser youtube.com... works well with only the Shockwave Flash Player installed but not the Flash Player. But why are there those two plugins?

Answer (score 2):

Shockwave (*not* "Shockwave Flash") is a web-optimized output format for [Director](http://www.adobe.com/products/director/) projects, normally meant for thick-client situations. Flash is a format that was designed for web use from the ground up.

Comment: But Shockwave can play flash contents?

Comment: Actually, Shockwave was always meant for web use as well. But it is a separate and more robust platform, and can embed Flash files within itself. The term ["Shockwave Flash"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adobe_Shockwave#Branding_and_name_confusion) is a relic of Macromedia's branding campaigns from the 90s.

Comment: @Lèse: But Director was not.

Comment: I suppose not, but what is the output format that Director uses for non-web projects?

Comment: @Lèse: I can't remember the specific name, but it's just a compiled version of the Director project that is intended to be run by a "projector" executable.